# Flutter adding list data into another list with specific name

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I want to add the data from into _list  another list where the name is NS200. The list contains data like this.

```
List<Posts> _list = [
{id: "0",
name: "assa ",},
{id: "1",
name: "NS200",}];.
```

I tried using were but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`where` returns an iterable which needs to be converted back to list as you are using list. Also, you are storing data incorrectly. List type is `Posts` so you must store posts in the list rather than a map or list of maps. See the below code:

```
class Posts {
  String id;
  String name;

  Posts({this.id, this.name});
}

void main() {

  List<Posts> _items = [
    Posts(
      id: "1",
      name: "NS200",
    ),
    Posts(
      id: "2",
      name: "assa",
    ),
    Posts(
      id: "3",
      name: "NS200",
    ),
  ];

  List<Posts> _newList = [];

  _newList = _items.where((item) => item.name == "NS200").toList();

  for (var item in _newList) {
    print('${item.id} - ${item.name}');
  }
}
```

With `where`, you can check whether the string you want to check matches with the name of every list item. If it matches, it will return true otherwise false. Then you can convert it to a list using `toList()`.

You can wrap the filter logic in a function so you can call it whenever you want.

```
List<Posts> _newList = [];

void filterList() {
 _newList = _items.where((item) => item.name == "NS200").toList(); 
}

filterList();

for (var item in _newList) {
  print('${item.id} - ${item.name}');
}
```

Comment: @Shreeya If this answer solved your problem, you can mark it as accepted answer by clicking the check mark beside the answer.

Comment: can that adding item in another list can be wrap in another function so that I can call in future..
if yes how?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code:

```
List list = [
  {'id': '0', 'name': 'assa '},
  {'id': '1', 'name': 'NS200'}
];
final copiedList = list.where((item) => item['name'] == 'NS200');
print(copiedList);
```

The result is:
`({id: 1, name: NS200})`